# How will implicitly expand the definition

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have the following code snippet:

```
override def A: MonadError[F, GenderError] = implicitly
```

that I would like to know, how the compiler will expand the definition.

I am not sure but I guess:

```
def implicitly[F[_]: MonadError[F, GenderError]](implicit e: MonadError[F, GenderError]): T = e
```

Could anyone please prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much more general than that:

```
def implicitly[A](implicit x: A) = x
```

So it returns the implicit value of whatever type you ask for the current scope, in this case `MonadError[F, GenderError]`.

Your own guess

> ```
> def implicitly[F[_]: MonadError[F, GenderError]](implicit e: MonadError[F, GenderError]): T = e
> ```

is not quite a special case, you should remove the context bound and fix the return type:

```
def implicitly[F[_]](implicit e: MonadError[F, GenderError]): MonadError[F, GenderError] = e
```

Comment: For this specific case it depends on what `F` is (it has to be defined in some outer scope). In general: well, if you write `implicit val x: String = ""; val y: String = implicitly` then `y` is `""`.

Comment: For instanace, `F` would be an `IO`, so it will return the `IO` value right?

Comment: Awesome explanation.

Comment: It will return a `MonadError[IO, GenderError]`. Look for its definition either in `MonadError` or `IO` companion objects. They might also inherit it from somewhere, in cats  https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/cats/effect/IO$.html mentions `extends IOInstances`which isn't documented.